# concavity of intervals of sin x

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

The definition of a convex function,is: "An interval is called convex if the line segment between any two points on the graph of the function lies above or on the graph."

Following this definition, does it make sense that sin x is concave on the interval:
\begin{align}[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}]\end{align}

and also convex on the interval:
\begin{align}[\pi,\frac{3\pi}{2}]\end{align}
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTnLh.png)

Comment: You got the wrong intervals. The sine is concave in $[0,\pi]$.

Answer (score 0):

> Following this definition, does it make sense that sin x is concave on the interval:
> \begin{align}[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}]\end{align}

No. Consider the points $(-\pi/2, -1)$ and $(0, 0)$ which lie on the graph of the function.
The line segment joining these two points is *above* the graph of the function.

Answer (score 0):

**A function cannot be both convex and concave on an interval unless it is linear.**

Based on this, $\sin x$ is convex over $[\pi,{3\pi\over 2}]$ and not concave (which concludes your second statement as true). For your first statement, note that $\sin x$ is also convex over $[-{\pi\over 2},0]$ and concave only over $[0,\pi]$ (you can obtain the latter results from the plot of $\sin x$ too)